# Using async/await to make sequential (blocking calls) returns too early

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

Below is simple example to demonstrate why I am trying to do using the fetch API. I am hoping that async fetchAsync() would block till it's returning data (or an exception) but the output shows that it doesn't.

`constructor
entering fetchAsync...
** we are here!!! **
leaving fetchAsync.
finish initialization`

I have been trying to figure out how to display the finish string (`we are here`) after `finish initialization` when my object is done initializing with the content of the file. Isn't await/async suppose to block till it's done?

```
class A {
    filename = "./resources/test.json";

    constructor() {
        console.log("constructor");
        this.fetchAsync(this.filename)
            .then( data => this.initialize(data)
            ).catch(reason => console.log(reason.message))
    }

    async fetchAsync(filename) {
        console.log("entering fetchAsync...");
        let data = await (await fetch(filename)).json();
        console.log("leaving fetchAsync.");
        return data;
    }

    initialize() {
        setTimeout(() => console.log("finish initialization"), 1000)
    }
}

let a = new A();
console.log("*** we are here!!! ***");
```

Answer (score 0):

`await` doesn't *block* - that would be very user and application unfriendly - it just waits for the promise to resolve before continuing, and can't be done on the top-level (yet). If you want `we are here` to display only after initialization is done, then you need to be able to access a promise that resolves once initialization is done, and then call `then` on it.

You should also ensure `initalize` returns a Promise so that it can be chained to the outer call on `a`.

So, you could try something like this:

```js
const dummyRequest = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000, 'response'));

class A {
  // filename = "./resources/test.json";
  constructor() {
    console.log("constructor");
  }
  startFetch() {
    return this.fetchAsync(this.filename || 'foo')
      .then(data => this.initialize(data)).catch(reason => console.log(reason.message))
  }
  async fetchAsync(filename) {
    console.log("entering fetchAsync...");
    // let data = await (await fetch(filename)).json();
    const data = await dummyRequest();
    console.log("leaving fetchAsync.");
    return data;
  }

  initialize() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("finish initialization");
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.startFetch()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("*** we are here!!! ***");
  });
```

Constructors can't be async, which is why I made the `startFetch` function.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I didn't know about limitation on constructors. I also don't think top-level await would be a good idea. The only caveat with the code written that way, is that the rest of my code (after init is done) should be call from then? It doesn't seem right to have something like `init().then(the_rest_of the application)`

Comment: Larger blocks of code should be in their own self-contained functions anyway. To apply that here, you could: `a.startFetch().then(main); ... function main() { /* code here */ }` With asynchronous code, there's no way around going down at least *one* line of indentation.

Comment: One last question, if you don't mind: can I also make the initialize() async if I prepend await in front of the setTimeout() call (or any other method doing heavy compute)..

Comment: Sure, `initialize` is already async (in my snippet), I'm assuming that the `setTimeout` is just a stand-in for something else. (but note that asynchronous-ness with Promises is different from synchronous heavy computation) You can't `await` a `setTimeout`, you can only `await` a Promise

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must be forgetting what `asyn`chronous means:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
      this.filename = "./resources/test.json";
      console.log("constructor");
      this.fetchAsync(this.filename)
          .then( data => this.initialize(data)
          ).catch(reason => console.log(reason.message))
  }

  async fetchAsync(filename){
      console.log("entering fetchAsync...");
      let data = await fetch(filename);
      console.log("leaving fetchAsync.");
      return data.json;
  }
  initialize() {
      setTimeout(() => {console.log("finish initialization"); console.log("*** we are here!!! ***"}, 1000)
  }
}
let a = new A();
```